# Javascript pass parameter to function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i try to pass paramater to function. When i click the div it will alert the paramater that i pass

i have 2 file

- index.html
- script.js

here's what i try

***Example 1***

**index.html**

```
<div id="thediv" >
```

**script.js**

```
window.onload = initialize;

    //bind event listener
        function initialize(){
             document.getElementById("thediv").onclick = myFunction(" something ");
        }
    //end of bind

    //function
        function myFunction(parameter) { alert( parameter ) };
    //end of all function
```

- the trouble is the function its executed without click

**Example 2**

**index.html**

```
<div id="thediv" onclick="myfunction('something')" >
```

**script.js**

```
function myFunction(parameter) { alert( parameter ) };
```

- yap its done with this but the trouble if i have many element in index.html it will painful to read which element have which listener
- i want to separate my code into 3 section (similiar with example1)

  - the view(html element)
  - the element have which listener
  - the function

what should i do? or can i do this?
(i don't want to use another library)

Comment: Did you include the .js file? If you put an alert in the script.js, does it pop up?

Comment: yes. i add it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first solution logic is absolutely ok .. just need to assign a **delegate** ... what you are doing is calling the function .. So do something like this ...

```
//bind event listener
        function initialize(){
             document.getElementById("thediv").onclick = function () { myFunction(" something "); };    
        }
//end of bind
```

Answer (score 3):

Placing `()` (with any number of arguments in it) will *call* a function. The return value (`undefined` in this case) will then be assigned as the event handler.

If you want to assign a function, then you need to pass the function itself.

```
...onclick = myFunction;
```

If you want to give it arguments when it is called, then the easiest way is to create a new function and assign that.

```
...onclick = function () {
        myFunction("arguments");
    };
```

Comment: thanks it good explanation. so if i want to pass argument, and want to separate the script and the element to make it more readable, the best thing i can do is your second code in my js file?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assign  you invoke a function with `myFunction();`
Use it like this

```
//bind event listener
 function initialize(){
    document.getElementById("thediv").onclick = function(){
         myFunction(" something ");
   }
 }
```